# Cannot create the final binary using tensorflow AOT compilation for CPU backend

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-xla

I followed the tutorial here: [TensorFlow AOT compilation](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/xla/tfcompile)

According to Step 1 and 2, I compiled the subgraph and generated the header (`test_graph_tfmatmul.h`) and object (`test_graph_tfmatmul.o`) files;

According to Step 3, I used the example code (named as `my_code.cc`) to invoke the subgraph;

According to Step 4, I added the code snippet `cc_binary` to the existing `BUILD` file (`//tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/BUILD`), and tried to create the final binary with the command:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary
```

but I got the following error:

```
undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests:my_binary':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/tfcompile_test.cc':
'/home/tensorFlow_src/tensorflow/tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/test_graph_tfmatmul.h'
```

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is finally figured out by using `tf_library` to build the `cc_library` in Step 2, instead of using `tfcompile` directly. I.e., `tf_library` will run `tfcompile` to generate the header and object files.

Please refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13482 for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel complaints that in the `tfcompile_test.cc` you `#include "tensorflow/compiler/aot/tests/test_graph_tfmatmul.h"`, but there is no dependency providing that header declared in the BUILD file. Did you add `":test_graph_tfmatmul"` into the deps of `my_binary`?

Comment: Yes, I added it. Here is the whole process I did: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13500. May I have your advice?